# Combining list of lists in python3.x

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of lists such as

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]]
```

I would like to combine it into one integer list as

```
[0,1,0,2,3,2,0,3,0,2,3]
```

I couldn't find a exact way how to achieve it.

The pattern is that if there is any number other than 0 in the list add it as actual number found or else enter it as 0.

Comment: What happens if two sub-lists have a non-zero number in the same position?

Comment: I'm confused as to how you "combine" them?  What happens if two lists have numbers in the same index?  And based on your example, the second list begins with a `1` but the result begins with `0`...can you expand on the rules for combining two of these lists?

Comment: @sedavidw It actually doesn't depend on position of the values in the first list of lists. My only criteria is to see if the list has all zeros if so then just in the new list append 0 or else append the actual value found. (The inside index of the list of list) is not of importance

Comment: What if the input [[0, 0], [1, 2]]? Is the expected output [0, 1, 2] or [0, 1] (i.e. only the first non-zero number in the list counts) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
3>> [functools.reduce(operator.or_, x) for x in L]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate like so:

```
new = [0 for i in range(len(old[0]))]

for a in old:
    for b, c in enumerate(a):
        new[b] += c
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to flatten the 2d list? If so, b in the following snippet is what you want:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [val for sublist in a for val in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

presuming you only get either all zeros or a single non zero digit you can call  `next` on `filter` after filtering all the 0's with 0 as the default value to `next`.

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]]


print([next(filter(None,sub),0) for sub in l] )
[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3]
```